# I accidentally removed a table without using a T-SQL query - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, snapshot, data-recovery

In my team's database, we had a table named "Dummy" so we removed the table, but later found out that we need the data from this table so now wish to recover it.

We do not have an active backup policy in SQL Server. Does anyone know if the tool does some sort of snapshot automatically at some point? If yes, where can we find this data?

When I said that we don't use a T-SQL Script, it's because we remove the table using the right bottom and made "Delete".

I've this backup policy but I can't the backup file in order to restore the database:

[image]

Comment: Now you know why you need backups. And the `Delete` menu option *does* execute a DELETE command. *Maybe* you can use some tool to recover data from the transaction log, using a tool like ApexSQL Log or ApexSQL Recover

Comment: @BogdanSahlean is a Simple Recovery Model. Do you know If I can recover some date based on the Log file (.ldf file)?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean I see in a query that I have a backup. But I can't find the .bak file to made the restore. See my update in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ApexSQL Recover](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_recover.aspx) can recover data lost due to a DELETE, TRUNCATE, or DROP TABLE operation.

Comment: please see my new comments

Comment: @John_Rodgers apexsql has 'help me decide' option, try it.